# Collision/overlapping in a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm writing a space invaders game on Khan Academy for a school project and I can't figure out how to put in a collision between bullets and the aliens and then get rid of the alien that the bullet collided with. It's very basic JS and as much as I've tried, I don't really understand how to put the other answers on this topic into my code. If anyone could help me on this I would be so grateful.

Here's a link to the game: http://www.khanacademy.org/cs/space-invaders/1087897437

I have another game with the same problem here: http://www.khanacademy.org/cs/brick/1176464164

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the game needs to run in a while loop. Basically, each iteration moves the game forward one 'frame'. One of the things to be calculated from one frame to the next, is whether or not a bullet has touched an alien.

Both a bullet and an alien have occupy a physical space. So you could effectively loop through all of the bullets and have a function that checks if a bullet has hit an alien.

```
function has_hit_alien(bullet) {
  for(var i = aliens.size; i > 0; i--){
    if(same_space(bullet, aliens[i]) {
      return aliens[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Now you need to implement the same_space function to check if any of the outer pixels of argument 1 are inside of argument 2.